# assigning d3 category colors to array of objects

Tags: d3.js

I want to assign a color property to each object in array. Is there any other elegant or efficient way to do it?

```
var objArr=[ //Need to attach different colors to each object in arry
    {label:"a"},
    {label:"b"},
    {label:"c"}
];
var domain_labels = [];
for(var i=0;i<objArr.length;i++){
    domain_labels.push(objArr[i].label)
}
var colors = d3.scale.category10();
colors.domain(domain_labels);
for(var i=0;i<objArr.length;i++){
    objArr[i].color = colors(domain_labels[i]) 
}

console.log(objArr);//[{"label":"a","color":"#1f77b4"},{"label":"b","color":"#ff7f0e"},{"label":"c","color":"#2ca02c"}]
```

Comment: Are the number of elements in your objArr going to be constant? If yes, then put all your colors in an array and reference using the index.
Else you can make an ordinal color scale.

Comment: No, Number of objects will vary

Comment: I think the way you followed is good. You can just reduce the lines of code as follows.`var objArr = [{ label: "a" }, { label: "b" }, { label: "c" }]; var colors = d3.scale.category10().domain(objArr.map(s => s.label)); objArr.forEach(function(ob, i) {  ob.color = colors(ob.label);  }); console.log(objArr);`

Comment: I would assign a class to each object, following some naming convention like `"clr-" + objArr[i].label` -- then add a CSS style for each of the possible color classes, and a default color for any other classes. That way, it's obvious if some of your objects fall outside the expected list of labels.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can use an ordinal scale to assign colors based on the labels but if all your labels are unique, you will still need have an array of colors for those many labels.
Here's a fiddle

```js
var objArr=[{label:"a"},{label:"b"},{label:"c"}];//Need to attach different colors to each object in arry
const map1 = objArr.map(x => x.label);
console.log(map1)
var colScale= d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#1f77b4","#ff7f0e","#2ca02c"]).domain(map1)

console.log(colScale("a"));
console.log(colScale("c"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

D3 also has color scales and colorbrewer that you can use

```
var colScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(map1)
    .range(colorbrewer.RdBu[9]);
```

Reference: [d3.scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#category10)